# for loop in r with variable names

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to repeat a complex syntax for a set of variables. Essentially,
using a data set like:

```
df <- data.frame( X=1:10, Y=6:15, Z=11:20)
```

I'd like to replace syntax like:

```
mean(df$X)
mean(df$Y)
mean(df$Z)
```

with a Loop like:

```
for (n in c("X", "Y", "Z")) {mean(df$n)}
```

However, this rather Stata-like programming does not work in R. It seems like the loop writes `df$"X"` instead of `df$X`. Is there a simple work around?

UPDATE: Instead of computing the mean I have a more complex function where I repeatedly need to access variable names. My question is therefor not about computing means but using the loop function.

Comment: How about `sapply(df,mean)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job.

```
for(n in c("X", "Y", "Z")) {mean(df[, n])}
```

To see the output, wrap `mean` in `print()`:

```
# [1] 5.5
# [1] 10.5
# [1] 15.5
```

I'd still favour @Prem's solution, but then I don't know exactly what you're doing...

Comment: Thanks!!! This alternative way to access the data column solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `summarise_at` along with `bind_cols`.

In below code I have applied `mean` on column `X, Y` & `max` on column `Y, Z`. Similarly you can apply your own function on multiple sets of different columns likewise.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  summarise_at(vars(X, Y), funs(Mean = mean)) %>%
  bind_cols(df %>%
              summarise_at(vars(Y, Z), funs(Max = max)))
```

which gives

```
  X_Mean Y_Mean Y_Max Z_Max
1    5.5   10.5    15    20
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(X = 1:10, Y = 6:15, Z = 11:20), .Names = c("X", 
"Y", "Z"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks, dplyr is a good hint for computing statistics. However, my problem is with the for-Loop (see UPDATE).